# This appeared in one of my PHP files

Tags: consensus, server

I have a test server that I use to practice some HTML and PHP. I once installed a hidden service to that server which has been running since i installed it and i kind of forgot about it. After restarting my server, first of all it did not boot. I had to run `fsck` from a stick to make it boot again. Now, one of my PHP files (contained in ../php/ from the html root dir) had gotten completely overwritten by this, which I could find out has something to do with "consensus" (I dont know much about tor):

```
network-status-version 3 microdesc
vote-status consensus
consensus-method 20
valid-after 2016-07-21 12:00:00
fresh-until 2016-07-21 13:00:00
valid-until 2016-07-21 15:00:00
voting-delay 300 300
client-versions 0.2.4.26,0.2.4.27,0.2.5.11,0.2.5.12,0.2.6.5-rc,0.2.6.6,0.2.6.7,0.2.6.8,0.2.6.9,0.2.6.10,0.2.7.1-alpha,0.2.7.2-alpha,0.2.7.3-rc,0.2.7.4-rc,0.2.7.5,0.2.7.6,0.2.8.1-alpha,0.2.8.2-alpha,0.2.8.3-alpha,0.2.8.4-rc,0.2.8.5-rc
server-versions 0.2.4.26,0.2.4.27,0.2.5.11,0.2.5.12,0.2.6.5-rc,0.2.6.6,0.2.6.7,0.2.6.8,0.2.6.9,0.2.6.10,0.2.7.1-alpha,0.2.7.2-alpha,0.2.7.3-rc,0.2.7.4-rc,0.2.7.5,0.2.7.6,0.2.8.1-alpha,0.2.8.2-alpha,0.2.8.3-alpha,0.2.8.4-rc,0.2.8.5-rc
known-flags Authority BadExit Exit Fast Guard HSDir Running Stable V2Dir Valid
params CircuitPriorityHalflifeMsec=30000 NumDirectoryGuards=3 NumEntryGuards=1 NumNTorsPerTAP=100 Support022HiddenServices=0 UseNTorHandshake=1 bwauthpid=1 cbttestfreq=60 pb_disablepct=0 usecreatefast=0
dir-source dannenberg 0232AF901C31A04EE9848595AF9BB7620D4C5B2E dannenberg.torauth.de 193.23.244.244 80 443
contact Andreas Lehner
vote-digest 10E11D27D445930AFF1FA10C494DD78EB2CD242E
dir-source tor26 14C131DFC5C6F93646BE72FA1401C02A8DF2E8B4 86.59.21.38 86.59.21.38 80 443
contact Peter Palfrader
vote-digest 0402275230BB177CBE6160D893865F4DD6CB5B83
dir-source longclaw 23D15D965BC35114467363C165C4F724B64B4F66 199.254.238.53 199.254.238.53 80 443
contact Riseup Networks <collective at riseup dot net> - 1nNzekuHGGzBYRzyjfjFEfeisNvxkn4RT
vote-digest AE2019C8987DE691B6B66EB35491E241D67EF473
dir-source maatuska 49015F787433103580E3B66A1707A00E60F2D15B 171.25.193.9 171.25.193.9 443 80
contact 4096R/23291265 Linus Nordberg <linus@nordberg.se>
vote-digest 611F988C0988555D74C6B26A6963C04558F7B134
dir-source moria1 D586D18309DED4CD6D57C18FDB97EFA96D330566 128.31.0.34 128.31.0.34 9131 9101
contact 1024D/28988BF5 arma mit edu
vote-digest 424D7E588C59BB9420B435B93BD04031B068ECFE
dir-source gabelmoo ED03BB616EB2F60BEC80151114BB25CEF515B226 131.188.40.189 131.188.40.189 80 443
contact 4096R/261C5FBE77285F88FB0C343266C8C2D7C5AA446D Sebastian Hahn <tor@sebastianhahn.net> - 12NbRAjAG5U3LLWETSF7fSTcdaz32Mu5CN
vote-digest 4D85030FC77729DC79FDE0EB5FD97815EBA11913
dir-source Faravahar EFCBE720AB3A82B99F9E953CD5BF50F7EEFC7B97 154.35.175.225 154.35.175.225 80 443
contact 0x0B47D56D Sina Rabbani (inf0) <sina redteam net>
vote-digest FBBFBB86351D39AC3D5E83A8F05D0CDD5E50C5FE
r PDrelay1 AAFJ5u9xAqrKlpDW6N0pMhJLlKs 2016-07-21 10:54:59 95.215.44.189 8080 0
m LlYs05UWIRq94KUbAMzfEJU5rCqP6OvfAvKS66dPnPk
s Fast Guard Running Stable Valid
v Tor 0.2.8.1-alpha-dev
w Bandwidth=5590
r seele AAoQ1DAR6kkoo19hBAX5K0QztNw 2016-07-20 20:03:33 24.6.164.192 9001 0
m tt3FDCHe7m3/KV0J/9zXQwXF5csTIYpdI9IFjTV+sOE
s Running Stable Valid
v Tor 0.2.7.6
w Bandwidth=21
r CalyxInstitute14 ABG9JIWtRdmE7EFZyI/AZuXjMA4 2016-07-21 04:14:07 162.247.72.201 443 80
m aFe4KRhmgn4ljX8W31GErGVDAWb9D1MBsgzMkr/PR5s
s Exit Fast Guard HSDir Running Stable V2Dir Valid
v Tor 0.2.7.6
w Bandwidth=19300
r Heady ABN21tHosR0B1Ineei9I+5NAN1U 2016-07-21 02:23:24 185.29.156.231 9050 9030
m Gci3Tc5+79uCB4x8Q0Ew83AI8rnfSmVRy8UwPGgRn/A
s Fast Running V2Dir Valid
v Tor 0.2.7.6
w Bandwidth=442
r Neldoreth ABUk3UA9cp8I9+XXeBPvEnVs+o0 2016-07-21 09:35:49 185.13.39.197 443 80
m nBQIiIGiOFckYSzPrxNw7ppnLN1ZfcG/gON1Ey+PiU0
s Fast Guard Running Stable V2Dir Valid
v Tor 0.2.7.6
w Bandwidth=11400
r kittensOnTor ABYeFS/PQzgBdvE7lkZWvSQ9bzM 2016-07-21 04:40:59 81.7.16.31 9001 9031
m U8OaFjAn7VhyAZoV66V5T30SGXLFuRCkaGZG7YMJ694
s Fast Guard Running V2Dir Valid
v Tor 0.2.6.10
w Bandwidth=10300
```

The actual file is way too long to post it here. Now the question: Basicly: wtf. How did it get there, what is it, why did it delete my PHP file and how do I prevent this from happening again?

Answer (score 1):

"How did it get there"

- No idea.

"what is it"

- It looks like a Tor network consensus document

"why did it delete my PHP file"

- It's a plain text file, it couldn't have.

"how do I prevent this from happening again?"

- Since no one has any idea how it happened, no one knows.